# Silverlight object not displayed in Firefox

Tags: c#, silverlight, firefox

I have checked that question:

[Firefox and Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448898/firefox-and-silverlight)

But I'm not using any 100% width or height nor using dynamic values. I'm not sure if it is due to a FF update, since that piece of HTML work perfectly fine ~ 2 weeks ago.

I'm specifying the width and height directly on the  like that:

```
<div id="silverlightControlHost" 
     style="height: 200px !important;width: 300px !important;position: fixed !important;">
  <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="300" height="200">
    <param name="source" value="/ClientBin/BunkerTimer.xap"/>
    <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
    <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="5.0.61118.0" />
    <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
    <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=5.0.61118.0" style="text-decoration:none">
    <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none;width: 400px !important;"/>
    </a>
</object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe>
</div>
```

I'm able to add a `background-color` and I see it correctly, it's just the Silverlight object that does not load up.

You can view it live here http://www.bunkerapp.com/addons. This work fine in Safari, Chrome and Internet Explorer.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: as-tu essayer d'ouvrir d'autre application silverlight avec FF pour voir si c'est seulement ton application ou bien si c'est generaliser?

Comment: @CarlT. : Although I'm not sure, I believe the preference is to stick to English on SO. So, translated: "Did you try to open other Silverlight apps with FF to see if this is a general issue or if it only affects your application?"

Comment: @spender I got carried away and did not even realize it!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that in Firefox, the `object` has a height of 0;

I got it working by adding an inline style attribute to the object element:

```
style="width:300px;height:200px"
```

Answer (score 3):

I solved this issue adding css style that is generated by silverlight test page inside Site.Master or _Layout.cshtml.

```
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
    }
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
    #silverlightControlHost {
        height: 100%;
        text-align:center;
    }
</style>
```